# Make Outlook default mail application on a Mac

Tags: mail.app, email

I used the directions referenced in many places to make Outlook the default mail application on a MAC (by going to MAIL and clicking the Mail menu - Preferences to set it).

I can not do that because Preferences is grayed out because I do not (nor am I allowed to on my work machine) have an iCloud account to reference in there or any other mail account. So what else can I do?

Comment: So the root problem is that Preferences is grayed out -- not the default email client?

Answer (score 1):

If it's greyed out, you obviously have an Admin restriction.  Your option is to get the Admin to change this setting for you.  I am assuming that Outlook is the default mail client of your organization.  Just explain to him/her that it's very inconvenient to have Mail as the default that always pops up when Outlook is the company standard.

Comment: This — I would assume the system admin would be more than willing to do this. It's out of your hands otherwise, unless you want to go around Administrative controls.